# How to return sequelize sum as json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How do I return value in json?

```
exports.get = id => Model.sum('price',
    {
        where: {
            id,
        }
    }
);
```

**result**

```
23
```

**desired**

```
{ sum: 23 }
```

Comment: If you want a JSON string instead of a primitive, just put it in an object and stringify the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in 2 ways :

**1. Simple change the response :**

```
exports.get = id => Model.sum('price',
    {
        where: {
            id,
        }
    }
).then(sum => {sum}); //<----- Little hack
```

**2. Use sequelize.fn** , Below one will return array , so you need to return the first element of array , for your expected result

```
exports.get = id => Model.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('price')), 'sum']] ,
  where : { id }
});
```